# "Bad src image pointers" error after calling setFrameNumber() on FFmpegFrameGrabber in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, video, javacv, video-editing

I am in the process of creating a small video editor and currently trying to get video files to display in the preview window. To do that, I want to get a frame of a video at a specific position using JavaCVs FFmpegFrameGrabber.

I have figured out a way of doing this, by setting the `frameNumber` variable of the `grabber` to the needed frame. However, this results in only the first frame of the file being displayed and some information about the file being printed out repeatedly (tell me if you need to see it, it's just kind of long and messy) alongside the error:

> [swscaler @ 000001927a7d3000] bad src image pointers

This is my frame grabbing class:

```
public class Video {

    private FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber;
    private final static Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

    public Video(File file) {
        this.grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(file);
        try {
            this.grabber.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage grabFrame(int framePos) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage frame;

        grabber.grabImage(); // Without this done before, the image is just black

        grabber.setFrameNumber(framePos);

        frame = converter.convert(grabber.grabImage());

        return frame;
    }
}
```

I am very thankful for your answers!

Comment: Calling `setFrameNumber()` only works approximately and only with constant frame rates. What happens if you use `setTimestamp()` instead? Do you also get an error? If so, that's probably a problem with the file...

Comment: Uuh, this is kind of embarassing, but it turns out I was just feeding the method a position outside of its length because my formula was broken... So, uhh, it works now. These error messages still pop up from time to time though.